# Python: Queue.get() from multiple threads (or signal)

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, signals

How can I use **Queue.get() from multiple threads** in Python?

I want to do: a thread sends a data with Queue.put(xxx), and some threads get the same data.
This idea is like "**signal**". I want to do this without PyQt.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue

queue= Queue.Queue()

def Func1():
  while True:
    data= queue.get()
    print 'Func1:got',data
    if data=='q':  break

def Func2():
  while True:
    data= queue.get()
    print 'Func2:got',data
    if data=='q':  break

def MainThread():
  while True:
    data= raw_input('q to quit > ')
    queue.put(data)
    if data=='q':  break

t1= threading.Thread(name='func1', target=Func1)
t2= threading.Thread(name='func2', target=Func2)
tm= threading.Thread(name='main', target=MainThread)
t1.start()
t2.start()
tm.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
tm.join()
```

Here I expect Func1 and Func2 get the same data from MainThread, but only one of Func1 and Func2 can get the data.

Please tell me if you have a nice idea.

Many thanks!

---

### Edited at 2014-12-19 12:51 EST

Based on the Reut Sharabani's idea, I implemented a signal class.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue

class TSignal:
  def __init__(self):
    self.queues= {}  #Map from index to queue
    self.counter= 0
    self.locker= threading.Lock()
  def NewQueue(self):
    with self.locker:
      idx= self.counter
      self.counter+= 1
      self.queues[idx]= Queue.Queue()
    queue= self.TQueue(self,idx,self.queues[idx])
    return queue
  def DeleteQueue(self,idx):
    with self.locker:
      del self.queues[idx]
  def put(self,item,block=True,timeout=None):
    for idx,queue in self.queues.iteritems():
      queue.put(item,block,timeout)
  class TQueue:
    def __init__(self,parent,idx,queue):
      self.parent= parent
      self.idx= idx
      self.queue= queue
    def __enter__(self):
      return self
    def __exit__(self,e_type,e_value,e_traceback):
      self.parent.DeleteQueue(self.idx)
    def get(self,block=True,timeout=None):
      return self.queue.get(block,timeout)

signal= TSignal()

def Func1():
  with signal.NewQueue() as queue:
    while True:
      data= queue.get()
      print '\nFunc1:got[%r]\n'%data
      if data=='q':  break

def Func2():
  with signal.NewQueue() as queue:
    while True:
      data= queue.get()
      print '\nFunc2:got[%r]\n'%data
      if data=='q':  break

def MainThread():
  while True:
    data= raw_input('q to quit > ')
    signal.put(data)
    if data=='q':  break

t1= threading.Thread(name='func1', target=Func1)
t2= threading.Thread(name='func2', target=Func2)
tm= threading.Thread(name='main', target=MainThread)
t1.start()
t2.start()
tm.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
tm.join()
```

The usage of TSignal is very simple.  In a getter function, insert a with statement like:

```
with signal.NewQueue() as queue:
```

then use queue in the same manner as Queue.get():

```
data= queue.get()
```

In a putter function, just use put as same as Queue.put():

```
signal.put(data)
```

**The problem is that if the number of threads is N, TSignal needs to maintain N queues, and TSignal.put calls Queue.put N times actually**. So I still want to know if there is a better idea.

Do you have any opinions about this?

Comment: Just to be clear. You want both threads to get the same data? So when I give "somestring" as input, the output should be "'Func1:got somestring" and "'Func2:got somestring"?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I want both (or more) threads to get the same data sent by a single sender.

Comment: Added another solution, way nicer I think.

Comment: Hey Reut, it's a nice workaround, I was wondering if there's any way to utilize here async for in order to speed up the dispatching to the queues? Could be a nice improvement! Also the code could use an update for Python 3.6+

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a queue per thread? If so, you could simply publish to each thread using it's own queue:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue

queue1 = Queue.Queue()
queue2 = Queue.Queue()


def func1():
    while True:
        data = queue1.get()
        print 'Func1:got', data
        if data == 'q':
            break


def func2():
    while True:
        data = queue2.get()
        print 'Func2:got', data
        if data == 'q':
            break


def main():
    while True:
        data = raw_input('q to quit > ')
        queue1.put(data)
        queue2.put(data)
        if data == 'q':
            break


t1 = threading.Thread(name='func1', target=func1)
t2 = threading.Thread(name='func2', target=func2)
tm = threading.Thread(name='main', target=main)
t1.start()
t2.start()
tm.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
tm.join()
```

### Edit:

For your follow up question in the comments, here is a mechanism with fixed number of synchronization primitives. The idea is to create tasks with the function and the message and submit them to a pool of threads to execute. (**Note:** python 3 has [Barriers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) which may become handy here if you choose another implementation):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

MAX_THREADS = 10

publish_queue = Queue.Queue()
print_lock = threading.Lock()


def sync_print(msg):
    print_lock.acquire()
    print msg
    print_lock.release()

# the manager actually holds a pool of threads
# he gives tasks to. The tasks are the functions you mean
# to execute zipped with the message.
def manager(functions):
    pool = ThreadPool(min(len(functions), MAX_THREADS))
    while True:
        sync_print("Manager waiting for message")
        message = publish_queue.get()
        sync_print("Manager got message %s" % message)
        if message == 'q':
            pool.close()
            pool.terminate()
            break;
        else:
            # create tasks of form: (function, message)
            tasks = zip(functions, [message] * len(functions))
            pool.map(lambda x: x[0](x[1]), tasks)


def func1(data):
    sync_print('%s:got %s' % (threading.current_thread().name, data))


def func2(data):
    sync_print('%s:got %s' % (threading.current_thread().name, data))


def main():
    while True:
        data = raw_input('q to quit > ')
        # wait for all threads to consume
        publish_queue.put(data)
        if data == 'q':
            break

# the functions you want to execute on each message - these were your threads
functions = [
    func1,
    func2
]

main = threading.Thread(name='main', target=main)
manager = threading.Thread(name='manager', target=manager, args=(functions, ))
manager.start()
main.start()

main.join()
```

Hope this fits your case as it may block a lot of processing time.

Comment: Thank you, this would be a simple solution. But if the number of threads is N, we need to maintain N queues, and the main thread need to execute queue.put N times. So if there is a better idea, I want to know it.

Comment: @Akihiko - added another solution using a ThreadPool by creating tasks for each "thread" (actually function). That's done by zipping each function in the list of functions and the message and treating the tuple as a task in the pool.

Comment: Thank you @Reut. Your idea of queue-per-thread is the best as far as I know. As you pointed out, the computation cost of queue-per-thread is not that much. My actual problem is to communicate between some state machines executed in parallel (they want to tell the state change events to the other state machines). I've just wanted to know a common solution to this problem because it seems to be a widely applicable problem. Anyway I edited my question based on your idea, and will use it if there is no better solution.

Comment: @Akihiko I did two edits, the first of which was not as good (but also worked) as the one currently posted. I think you can communicate the message using the queue in this implementation, but I don't really have your code to verify :)

Comment: I didn't know ThreadPool; I will check it. Thank you for the second solution. I've got the idea. For my problem solution 1 is better, but it would be an alternative solution to those kinds of problem.